# Seaborn heatmap dendrogram

Tags: heatmap, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I'm a beginner at python, I plotted a heatmap dendrogram and I want to add the distance (as an axis) value of clustering as shown below pic. Should I write a separate code or I can use the heatmap statement?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/21f3r.png]